# Passing a datatable to RDLC Report as DataSource

Tags: c#-4.0

I am using RDLC Report in my .net's window application. At a stage i have some values in a datatable which i have to print with RDLC Report.

But a RDLC Report use a typed dataset as a datasource. 
Can i pass a datatable instead of typed dataset, if u have any idea then please share with me.

Thanks

DevKASHYAP

Answer (score 2):

Add a datatable with columns manually to one of your xsd file. Then add that dataset to your rdlc report and pass that datatable from form like this:

```
rptDataSource = new ReportDataSource("sp name from rdlc", dtname);
rptViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rptDataSource);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can specify other data sources instead of Typed dataset. You can use XML schema at the time of creating the Report, and after that assign the DataSet dynamically through code. Here is a link of Sample for this solution.

[Binding DataSet at Runtime](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/reportdisplay.aspx)